# Finding the number of pairs in an integer Array

Tags: array, kotlin

This function returns the number of pairs of the same elements in the array

It takes, array length and the array as the parameter

> > n: Length of array
> >
> > ar: Array of integers for example
> >
> > 4 6 7 8 7 6 6 7 6 4
>
> returns 4

```
fun getNumberOfPairs(n: Int, ar: Array<Int>): Int {
    val enteries = HashSet<Int>()
    var pairs = 0

    for (i in 0 until n) {
        if (!enteries.contains(ar[i])) {
            enteries.add(ar[i])
        } else {
            pairs++
            enteries.remove(ar[i])
        }
    }

    println(pairs)
    return pairs
}
```

How can we write this code in a better way for readability/performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall it's very readable and fast already. Good job.

I have some suggestions for possible improvements:

- As `n` must be equal to `ar.size`, you could drop that parameter from the method and use `ar.size` in place of `n` within the method body.
- This method is a pure function except for the side effect of printing the result. Being a "pure function" is often a good thing so you can move the printing of the result to outside the method. Printing something is also quite time-consuming.
- Your method could easily support more than `Int`, it doesn't have to be restricted by a specific type. You could check for duplicates of any type so we can make this method generic.
- As you are iterating over elements you could use `for (e in ar)` instead of iterating over the indexes with `for (i in 0 until n)`. This would make it more efficient for data structures that doesn't have a \$O(1)\$ lookup-time, for example `LinkedList`.
- The method `HashSet.add` returns `false` if the value already exists, so you don't need the call to `.contains`.
- There is a typo in the name `enteries`, it should be called `entries`.
- `ar` could be called `input` to make it more readable.

After applying all of the above, this is what you would end up with:

```
fun <T> getNumberOfPairs(input: Array<T>): Int {
    val entries = HashSet<T>()
    var pairs = 0

    for (e in input) {
        if (!entries.add(e)) {
            pairs++
            entries.remove(e)
        }
    }
    return pairs
}
```